# Adding watermarks to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

How to add watermarks like "Enter textarea" for a textarea.

```
   <textarea rows = "8" cols = "18" border ="0" class="input" style="border: none;" WRAP id="details" name ="details"></textarea>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you mean placeholder?

In HTML5:

`<textarea placeholder="Enter textarea"></textarea>`

In HTML4:

`<textarea onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter textarea') this.value = '';">Enter textarea</textarea>`

Comment: In this if the user enters a text  and again clicks on the textarea it becomes null again....

Comment: change "onclick" to "onfocus" and "this.value == 'Enter textarea'" to "this.value == this.defaultValue" and this works extra-well!

Comment: The full answer is for focused and not focused is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3329751/950427. I gave you the upvote as well!

Answer (score 1):

i have written a jquery code for my purposes.
i think it might be excellent for your problem

to use it for any of your textarea/text field, you just have to add 'watermark' class & add 'placeholder' attribute with the watermark value to it.

e.g `<textarea rows="2" placeholder="Post your question here" name="query_area" id="query_area" class="watermark">Post your question here</textarea>`

the jquery code is as below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".watermark").each(function(){
       $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });

    $(".watermark").focus(function(){

        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        var current_value = $(this).val();
        $(this).css('color', '#192750');
        if(current_value == placeholder) {
            $(this).val('');


        }

    });

    $(".watermark").blur(function(){

        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        var current_value = $(this).val();

        if(current_value == '') {
            $(this).val(placeholder);
            $(this).css('color', '#676767');
        }

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. One of them is that all form elements have <label for="XX"> and all elements have <element id="XX"> so that you know to which element label belongs. Then in CSS you hide some labels, and with JS you check all hidden labels, and write label title/content to the form elements, if that element is empty. Then with JS you show and hide this text based on hover and inputed text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice one using jQuery

[**jQuery Watermark**](http://daersystems.com/jquery/watermark/)

Comment: This link is broken

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
<input type="text"   name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value=""/ class="googlesearch" onfocus="if(this.value != '') this.className = 'googlesearch2'" onblur="if(this.value == this.defaultValue) this.className = 'googlesearch'" />
```

from [link](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=129962)

hope that will help.