# Why does textArea not update?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have checked with an alert, my value is "Enter your comment...", but my if statement returns false.

Thank you.

```js
function ClearText(e) {

  //alert(document.getElementById('contactMe').value);
  if (document.getElementById('contactMe').value == 'Enter your comment...') {
    document.getElementById('contactMe').value = "";
  }

}


var x = document.getElementById('contactMe');
x.addEventListener('click', ClearText, false);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id=contactMe rows=4 cols=40>Enter your comment...</textarea>
  <script src="contactBox.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding watermarks to textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536221/adding-watermarks-to-textarea)

Comment: I see the script working. After i clicked on the textarea, automatically removed the text "Enter your comment...". Isn't it what you are trying to get?

Comment: Code Snippet is working , what is the issue then?

Comment: Yes, Xahed Kamal. I just realized that it does work on site, but in my browser it does not.

Comment: Please check is there any javascript is there and conflict

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to accomplish and you can avoid the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) all together by using the html attribute [placeholder](http://caniuse.com/#search=input-placeholder).

Consider the following code.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id=contactMe rows=4 cols=40 placeholder='Enter your comment...'></textarea>
  <script src="contactBox.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it too as follows:

```js
function clearText(field){
 if(field.defaultValue == field.value){
  field.value = "";
 }
 else if(field.value == ""){
  field.value = field.defaultValue;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id=contactMe rows=4 cols=40 onfocus="clearText(this);" onblur="clearText(this);">Enter your comment...</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute to do this

```
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id="contactMe" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Enter your comment..."></textarea>
  <script src="contactBox.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Be informed that this is not supported in IE8 and you have to use javascript for that

My favourite plugin to do this is [Mathias](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder). Go for it if you need to support IE8. Also you have not used double quotes in your html for attributes (**id="contactMe"**). (though it will work without it, it is [recommended by w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) to use quotes)

If you need a full jQuery solution you can use the below code. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j9ysxbL/)

```
var placeholderText = "Enter your comment...";

$(document).on("click","#contactMe",function(e){
 if($(this).val()=="" ||$(this).val() == placeholderText ){
  $(this).val("");
}
});

$(document).on("focusout","#contactMe",function(e){

    if($(this).val()==""){
      $(this).val(placeholderText);
    }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#contactMe").val(placeholderText);
});
```

Comment: Double quotes are not required. Additionally, while not customary, unless there is a space, the quotes are not needed at all in [tag:html]. The placeholder part looks familiar from 40 minutes ago too...

Comment: yeah, i have also added jQuery solution which will also support IE8

Comment: Which double quotes are not required?

Comment: i guess he was mentioning the double quotes in id="contactMe"

Comment: @Jesse added refereces to w3 where it recommends usage of single or double quotes